# Как запустить код с venv на python через bat'ник

Tags: python, telegram-bot, bat

код bat файла:

```
@echo off

call %~dp0tg_bot\venv\Scripts\activate

cd %~dp0tg_bot

set TOKEN= токен бота

python bot_tg.py

pause
```

[image: -]

При запуске ошибка:
[image: -]

[image: -]

Comment: Вы устанавливали aiogram?

Comment: Да, прикрепила скрин

Comment: Поменяйте название папки в которой лежит бот. Из-за пробела в названии он багает

Comment: В чём-то другом проблема...
Не исправляется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил у себя, получил ту же проблему, и она в пробеле и наверное кириллице. Короче фикситься оборачиванием в кавычки пути.

```
@echo off

call "%~dp0tg_bot\venv\Scripts\activate"

cd "%~dp0tg_bot"

set TOKEN= токен бота

python bot_tg.py

pause
```

Comment: А почему из-за кавычек этих решается проблема?